# Apply PCA on very large sparse matrix

Tags: language-agnostic, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, pca

I am doing a text classification task with R, and I obtain a document-term matrix with size 22490 by 120,000 (only 4 million non-zero entries, less than 1% entries). Now I want to reduce the dimensionality by utilizing PCA (Principal Component Analysis). Unfortunately, R cannot handle this huge matrix, so I store this sparse matrix in a file in the "Matrix Market Format", hoping to use some other techniques to do PCA.

So could anyone give me some hints for useful libraries (whatever the programming language), which could do PCA with this large-scale matrix with ease, or do a longhand PCA by myself, in other words, ***calculate the covariance matrix at first, and then calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the covariance matrix***.

What I want is to ***calculate all PCs (120,000), and choose only the top N PCs, who accounts for 90% variance***. Obviously, in this case, I have to give a threshold a priori to set some very tiny variance values to 0 (in the covariance matrix), otherwise, the covariance matrix will not be sparse and its size would be 120,000 by 120,000, which is impossible to handle with one single machine. Also, the loadings (eigenvectors) will be extremely large, and should be stored in sparse format.

Thanks very much for any help !

Note: I am using a machine with 24GB RAM and 8 cpu cores.

Comment: I an not sure if it's 100% right, but I think that MatLab can do the job.

Comment: If you don't get any joy here, it might be worth asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @aix Thanks for your advices, I've moved it to the computational science beta, and get some useful hints. You may also follow it at this [URL](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/apply-pca-on-very-large-sparse-matrix)

Comment: @EnsomHodder: I didn't know about that new site. Looks interesting, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 15):

The Python toolkit [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) has a few PCA variants, of which [`RandomizedPCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA) can handle sparse matrices in any of the formats supported by [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). [`scipy.io.mmread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmread.html#scipy.io.mmread) should be able to parse the Matrix Market format (I never tried it, though).

Disclaimer: I'm on the scikit-learn development team.

**EDIT**: the sparse matrix support from `RandomizedPCA` has been deprecated in scikit-learn 0.14. `TruncatedSVD` should be used in its stead. See the documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot @larmans, to some degree, your proposed method can do PCA with the sparse matrix, but it can only calculate some small amount of PCs, due to the large memory consumption :-(

Comment: Note that `RandomizedPCA` has been deprecated in favor of `PCA` with keyword argument `svd_solver='randomized'`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of running PCA, you could try Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA), which decomposes the document-word matrix into a document-topic and topic-word matrix. Here is a link to an R implementation: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lda/ - there are quite a few implementations out there, though if you google.

With LDA you need to specify a fixed number of topics (similar to principle components) in advance. A potentially better alternative is HDP-LDA (http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~ywteh/research/npbayes/npbayes-r21.tgz), which learns the number of topics that form a good representation of your corpus.

If you can fit our dataset in memory (which it seems like you can), then you also shouldn't have a problem running the LDA code.

As a number of people on the scicomp forum pointed out, there should be no need to compute all of the 120k principle components. Algorithms like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration calculate the largest eigenvalues of a matrix, and LDA algorithms will converge to a minimum-description-length representation of the data given the number of topics specified.

Answer (score 1):

In R `big.PCA` of `bigpca` package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigpca/bigpca.pdf does the job.

Answer (score 0):

> text classification task

I resolved [almost same problem](https://github.com/niitsuma/wordca) using a  [technique for PCA of sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274972/2223158) .
This technique can handle very large sparse matrix.
[The result](https://github.com/niitsuma/wordca/blob/master/demo.sh) shows such simple PCA outperfoms word2vec.
It intends the simple PCA outperforms LDA.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wouldn't be able to compute all principle components. But still you can obtain reduced dimension version of your dataset matrix. I've implemented a simple routine in MATLAB, which can easily be replicated in python.

Compute the covariance matrix of your input dataset, and convert it to a dense matrix. Assuming S is you input 120,000 * 22490  sparse matrix, this would be like:

```
Smul=full(S.'*S);
Sm=full(mean(S));
Sm2=120000*Sm.'*Sm;
Scov=Smul-Sm2;
```

Apply eigs function on the covariance matrix to obtain the first N dominant eigenvectors,

```
[V,D] = eigs(Scov,N);
```

And obtain pcs by projecting the zero centered matrix on eigenvectors,

```
Sr=(S-Sm)*V;
```

Sr is the reduced dimension version of S.