# what could be the best tool or package to perform PCA on very large datasets?

Tags: r, pca, large-data

This might seem like a similar question which was asked in this URL ([Apply PCA on very large sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718455/apply-pca-on-very-large-sparse-matrix)).

But I am still not able to get my answer for which i need some help. I am trying to perform a PCA for a very large dataset of about 700 samples (columns) and > 4,00,000 locus (rows). I wish to plot "samples" in the `biplot` and hence want to consider all of the 4,00,000 locus to calculate the principal components.

I did try using `princomp()`, but I get the following error which says,

```
Error in princomp.default(transposed.data, cor = TRUE) : 
'`princomp`' can only be used with more units than variables
```

I checked with the forums and i saw that in the cases where there are less units than variables, it is better to use `prcomp()` than `princomp()`, so i tried that as well, but i again get the following error,

```
Error in cor(transposed.data) : allocMatrix: too many elements specified
```

So I want to know if any of you could suggest me any other good option which could be best suited for my very large data. I am a beginner for statistics, but I did read about how PCA works. I want to know if there are any other easy-to-use R packages or tools to perform this?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find your vocabulary ambiguous when describing your data. The convention is that columns correspond to *variables* and rows correspond to *observations*. Don't you have 700 variables (or dimensions) and 4,000,000 observations (or points)? If so, then you should not transpose your data before passing it to `princomp`.

Comment: @flodel I am not an expert, but I believe in genetics it is very common for that to be reversed.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Iterative_computation.

Comment: Read about the FactoMineR package in bioconductor site.I believe it is capable of handling large data sets.