# PCA on large Sparse matrix using Correlation matrix

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, machine-learning, sparse-matrix

I have a large (500k by 500k), sparse matrix. I would like to get the principle components of it (in fact, even computing just the largest PC would be fine). Randomized PCA works great, except that it is essentially finding the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix instead of the correlation matrix. Any ideas of a package that will find PCA using the covariance matrix of a large, sparse matrix? Preferably in python, though matlab and R work too.

(For reference, a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718455/apply-pca-on-very-large-sparse-matrix) but the methods refer to covariance matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Are they not the same thing? As far as I understand it, the correlation matrix is just the covariance matrix normalised by the product of each variable's standard deviation. And, if I recall correctly, isn't there a scaling ambiguity in PCA anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried irlba package in R - "The IRLBA package is the R language implementation of the method. With it, you can compute partial SVDs and principal component analyses of very large scale data. The package works well with sparse matrices and with other matrix classes like those provided by the Bigmemory package." you can check [here](http://bigcomputing.blogspot.de/2011/05/bryan-lewiss-vignette-on-irlba-for-svd.html) for details